# Injection of map typed properties using p: namespace

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

With `p namespace` we can define properties like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass"
p:name="abc"
p:address="hell"> 
</bean>
```

But how can we inject following property *using p namespace*?

```
<property name="myproperty">
        <map>
            <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
            <entry key="Key 2" value-ref="PersonBean" />
                 ...
        </map>
    </property>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Why would you want to?  Even if you could, it would be completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mix both styles:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass"
    p:name="abc"
    p:address="hell"> 

    <property name="myproperty">
        <util:map>
           <util:entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
           <util:entry key="Key 2" value-ref="PersonBean" />
             ...
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I hope this is the answer for the question.

If you really asked about something like:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanClass"
   p:name="abc"
   p:address="hell"
   p:myProperty="'Key 1'='1';'Key 2'=PersonBean"  > 
</bean>
```

ask yourself if you really want to read such code (*and no, **this syntax does not exist**, it is only an example to show how unreadable it is*)